# Create cookie from a function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

this is my router

```
router.post('/hello', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    res.send(welcome(name));
});
```

and this is my welcome function

```
function welcome(name) {
    console.log(name)
    // create cookie here
}
```

how can I create a cookie in the welcome function should I pass **req** and **res** along the **name** to that function?
is this the right approach? thank you

Answer (score 0):

From technical point of view yes you need to set the cookie on the `res` object so, the `res` object should be passed where you need it!

Pass `req` and `res` (and eventually `next`) is the right approach because is express middleware friendly [Express middleware docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Answer (score 0):

Need to use cookieParser().

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```

Then you need to set the cookies example below

```
function welcome(name) {
    //set cookies
    res.cookie('test', 'Welcome data');
}
```

Then get the cookies in separate router

```
router.get('/cookies', (req, res) => {
    //get cookies
    res.send(req.cookies.test);
});
```